# How to make something like Area Contents in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So we have installed SP 2013 for corporate portal and created a structure for Departments site.

What we want to have - something like Table of contents for the site, which will list all the subsites (departments) and their subsites. I know about the Table of contents web part. But I don't need all that Home, Documents, Site Contents staff. I need only Subsites structure.

In SP 2003 there was a nice web part - Area Contents, which did exactly what we need.

How to make it for 2013?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved by customizing [Table Of Contents web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.tableofcontentswebpart%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

[Table Of Contents web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.tableofcontentswebpart%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is XSL based web part, the following table lists and describes the two XSL files that describe the Table Of Contents Web Part:

**TableOfContentsMain.xsl**

Location: `\Style Library\XSL Style Sheets\TableOfContentsMain.xsl`

Description:

- Contains logic that generates the appropriate nodes.
- Contains functions that help designers modify the Level transforms.
- Receives all the content, parses it, and sends appropriate pieces to
  the LevelStyle  template.
- Maintains the structure of the Table of Content Web Part.

**LevelStyle.xsl**

Location: `\Style Library\XSL Style Sheets\LevelStyle.xsl`

Description: Contains templates that define how to display an level.

### How to render site structure using [Table Of Contents web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.tableofcontentswebpart%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Since it is not recommended to modify SharePoint out-of-the-box XSL files, we will create custom file named `SiteLevelStyle.xsl` (copy of `LevelStyle.xsl`)

Solution: in order to exclude nodes except site nodes we are going to modify `node-template` template in `SiteLevelStyle.xsl`

To render only site nodes you could use the following code (filter to exclude non site nodes):

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@Path) > 0 and not(contains(@Path, 'viewlsts.aspx')) and not(contains(@Path, '/Lists/')) and not(contains(@Path, '/Forms/')) and not(contains(@Path, 'WopiFrame.aspx')) and (@Title != 'Home') and (@Title != 'Recent') ">

  <!-- remaining code from node-template goes here... -->  

</xsl:if>
```

You could grab the final `SiteLevelStyle.xsl` file from [here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/10109436).

### How to apply changes

- Upload `SiteLevelStyle.xsl` into `Style Library` (`/Style Library/XSL
  Style Sheets/`)
- Export Table Of Contents web part
- Open web part file and specify property `ItemXslLink` value to
  `/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/SiteLevelStyle.xsl`
- Upload the modified web part file and add imported web part on page

### Results

Displaying site structure using customized Table Of Contents web part

[image]